# Looking for an antivirus that can be shut down

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I've recently tried the highly-rated Bitdefender.
I was satisfied, except for one problem: it was not possible to shut it down.

I believe that this is a common trait of antivirus software these days, but it's hard for me to accept.

I like to be in control of my own machine (which is one of the reasons I don't upgrade to Windows 10).

I am a power user, and if I decide it makes sense to turn off the antivirus (for whatever reason) then it should be possible.

I corresponded with Bitdefender on this. They claim that shutting down is prevented for security reasons. Obviously this concern can be overcome, by making this ability an advanced configuration, and maybe password-protected.

I'm looking for high quality, reliable AV software that can be shut down. And I mean completely shut down. Not "turn off notifications" / "suspend monitoring" / "disable-but-stay-in-memory until restart".

I want any and all services, processes and injected DLLs stopped, shut down and dejected, when I turn it off.

Unfortunately this "feature" is not advertised (as far as I could see) on vendors' websites.

Can anyone recommend such an AV?

Note that pricing is not a factor, but it does need to come from a reputable vendor, or at least to have been subjected to some sort of "professional scrunity".

EDIT: please refrain from giving answers or comments that are aimed at teaching me about security or best practices. If you have an actual answer then it would be REALLY appreciated.

Comment: The whole idea of an antivirus is that it is highly resistant to being disabled - otherwise guess what the first attack vector would be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not shut down Anti Virus. This is not a good strategy. Make a specific folder for downloads and (only if necessary) whitelist this folder. Only use this folder for downloads, not any random folder. Then, only if necessary, whitelist applications.

I use Windows Defender, it is always on, and I have very few whitelists.

For Windows 7, Symantec Endpoint Protection is very good.SEP can be shut down for a time (as long as needed). I have used this when we had Windows 7. I will have to check Security Essentials. SEP is more manageable for sure.

Editorial comment :) The very time you shut of AV, you will be attacked and defenseless - Murphy's Law

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I appreciate the concern but it's not necessary.

Comment: BTW, here's a use-case for you: after a full scan, the AV memory-resident process reaches 5GB. I just want it restarted, but it can't be done. Another use-case: some stuff slows down. I suspect the AV but not 100% sure. Whitelisting makes no difference. I want to disable it for 10 minutes to see if it makes a difference. Cannot. Have to uninstall.

Comment: You may wish to find an Anti Virus that better fits your needs then

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do here...

Comment: Windows 7 needs to be replaced and Windows 10 Defender with EMET (V1709 and above) is excellent.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that runs on Windows 7

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials runs on Windows 7 and is decent. Symantec Endpoint Protection (corporate edition) runs on Windows 7 and is excellent. There are others as well.

Comment: can they be shut down? (without uninstall and without a reboot)

Comment: SEP can be shut down. I have used this when we had Windows 7.  I will have to check Security Essentials. SEP is more manageable for sure.

Comment: ok, sounds good! I will try it out, thanks! If it can indeed be shut down, and you put this info in your answer (instead or alongside the recommendation to not do what I ask for) then I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to address your request

Comment: Hmm... what does it mean "can be shut down for a time"? If it's this "shut down for 30 minutes" then in my experience this is not a true shutdown, but just suspension of scanning.

Comment: "for a time" can mean as long as needed. I re-phrased my answer

Comment: Ok. It seems that buying SEP requires going through a reseller. So I'll approve your answer based on faith and will look further into it next week. Thanks again.

Comment: Once we had Sophos Anti-Virus and you could disable it via `net stop ...` (e.g. during backup to speed it up by more than 300%) by stopping a specific service. Unfortunately more recent version automatically restarted the service after a few minutes...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is best for you to leave your Anti-Virus software on at all times, but there is a AV software that I know of that **CAN** be shut down or turned off. But I still don't recommend turning your AV off.

Avast Anti-Virus is one of the most trusted and used anti-virus software out there, when downloaded, you can choose to disable the AV at the task-bar menu (at the bottom right) and select the Avast AV Logo and go to - **Avast shields control > Disable for 10 min** / 1 hour / permanently.

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDTei.jpg)

Again, this isn't recommended.

Comment: Thank you, but from my personal experience Avast is terrible, and half malware in its own right, and also its "Disable" mechanism doesn't really shut down, just suspends scanning. At least that's how it was in the version I last tried a few years back...

Comment: @obe After you click the disable button on Avast, there's a pop-up saying "An attempt has been made to turn of a key Avast module (All shields). This may be a legitimate action, but could also be the result of a malware attack." Reading from that, it seems like it's pretty serious.

Comment: ok, in that case you may be right. I already accepted John's answer, but if eventually I find that SEP doesn't turn off but Avast does, then I will accept your answer instead. Thank you!

Comment: I've found the main problem with Avast [& this applies to Win and Mac] is that it noticeably drags on a system - you can 'feel' it working.